# "Void methods cannot return a value" - processing 3 in java

Tags: java, constructor, return, processing, void

I'm working on a snake game in java, and I made a "void" function inside a snake class, that returns if the snake eats the food. when trying to execute, the console shows me "Void methods cannot return a value". how could you return a "true" or "false" inside the "void" function?

Thanks for any help! Alon.

Comment: If you want to return something, don't make it void.

Comment: If you want to return true or false, then why not simply make the function return `boolean` instead? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, `void` means that the function doesn't return anything. You can still `return;` (with no value) to end the function early, but you can't return with a value.

To return a `boolean`, change `void` to `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Void does not have a return type, you'll need to change the method to `boolean` and not `void`

Answer (score 1):

Change the function from `void` to `boolean`.
That way you return a `True` of `False`.
but make sure your function returns something. it must contain 'return xxx' and the xxx should be a variable or a `True` of `False`.